# Cannot use the special principal 'sa' - ant sql task

Tags: sql-server, ant

I am trying to execute an ant sql task, which is supposed to execute a number of queries to a local database. I already enabled the 'sa' user, it is the dbo of of the database, the authentication to the server is mixed mode and I still get the following exception, when trying to run it:

[sql-exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQWdg.png)

I already read and tried everything possible about the exception, so if somebody has any idea how to solve this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the specific query you get this error on. It sounds like it could be a very specific action like [`sp_changedbowner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-changedbowner-transact-sql) or [`ALTER AUTHORIZATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-authorization-transact-sql) and (trying to) add extra roles to `sa`.

Comment: The query is the following:  IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT principal_id FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'sa') CREATE USER sa FOR LOGIN sa . It tries to create sa user, but it cannot. I checked and the sa user is not in the sys.database_principals. Is it possible to add it?